# unable to use the superclass object in 2nd Test Class but can use it in the 1st Test Class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng, testng-eclipse

I have  superclass named BaseTest with code

```
public class BaseTest {
    public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
    DesiredCapabilities cap;
    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters("device")
    public void SetUpForDriver(String device) throws MalformedURLException{
        if(device.equalsIgnoreCase("emulator")){
            cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "7.1.1");
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "SlingEmulator");
            //cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
            cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.edmobilelabs.sling.dev");
            //cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.edmobilelabs.sling.ui.ScrSplash");
            cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.edmobilelabs.sling.ui.ScrSplash");
            driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

    }
        else{
            cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "6.0");
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "28A4AA040IG4012");
            cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.edmobilelabs.sling.dev");
            cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.edmobilelabs.sling.ui.ScrSplash");
            driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        }
    }
}
```

My Ist Test class which I am able to execute successfully

```
public class LogInPageTest extends BaseTest {
    LogInPage log;

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void navigateToLoginPageTest() throws MalformedURLException{
        log = new LogInPage(driver);
        boolean isTestCaseVerified = log.navigateToLoginPage();
        Assert.assertTrue(isTestCaseVerified,"Test Case is Passed");
    }
}
```

My 2nd Test class In which I want to use driver object

```
public class HomePageTest extends BaseTest{

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void firstChatWithBots(){
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='How Sling Works']")).click();
    }
}
```

I have two Test classes 
My test class where I perform the login operation passed successfully but in my 2nd Test Class not able to use my driver object

Can somebody what is going on with my code

Comment: Can you please give me the link of the question so I can see

Comment: I dont think this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) question. The fix for this problem is to get rid of the "@BeforeTest" annotation and instead replace it with "@BeforeClass" annotation because "@BeforeTest" gets executed only once per "<test>" tag. That explains why the second test always skips the initialisation.

Comment: Just by seeing Null Pointer doesn't mean that this is answered over there
No such type of scenario is present over there
So please read the question 1st and then mark it as duplicate

Comment: Please follow the recommendations that I have given in my comment. That will fix your problem. I have also briefly explained the cause of this.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan
I have one question I am already logged in So if I use BeforeClass Then it would re-instantiate the whole app
As per I think

Comment: Yes it would. If you don't want that to happen, then you would need to re-engineer your test such that this doesn't happen. But using "@BeforeTest" to initialise your webdriver is not going to work here.